# Fetch post a api no funciona bien

Tags: javascript, html, nodejs, api, webapi

Hola buenas quería comentaros un problema que no me deja ni dormir.
Resulta que estoy haciendo una web para un trabajo de la uni y necesito hacer un login, conectándome a la API. Al principio todas las peticiones funcionan bien, o al menos eso parecía porque conectarse se conecta.
El problema viene cuando hago una petición POST y es que el contenido de Request está vacío, no le llega nada a la api y he probado miles de cosas, obviamente incluyendo el atributo body (probando miles de formas de mandar información json y simples strings). He probado hacerlo con petición GET pero así tampoco. Lo estoy haciendo con nodejs ( y los módulos correspondientes) y la web en html css y js.
Si me resolvéis esto os lo agradecería porque estoy desesperado, muchísimas gracias de antemano

```js
var data = { a: "blabla"}
async function entra(data) {
    await fetch('http://localhost:3000/api/login',{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(data) 
    })
}
```

```js
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');   // Módulo que convierte los datos que llegan en JSON
const express = require('express');    // Framework de NODE, crea nuestra estructura del servidor
const morgan = require('morgan');    // Módulo que nos permite ver por consola los cambios en el servidor
const mongoose = require('mongoose');    // Módulo de MongoDB que nos provee de métodos y funcionalidades

const jwt = require('jwt-simple');
const cors = require('cors');    // Módulo JWT, autenticación por tokens
const config = require('./config/config');   // Fichero de configuración 
const path = require('path');
const app = express();
require('node-fetch');

const routes = require('./rutas/all.js');    // Único fichero de rutas en uso.    

// Conexión a la BD
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
//mongoose.connect('mongodb://usuario:contraseña@host:puerto/nombre_BD');  Esta será la conexión real
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/restapi-local', {    // Conexión a BD de prueba en local
 useNewUrlParser: true,
 useUnifiedTopology: true
}).then(db => console.log('Base de datos conectada'))
 .catch(err => console.log(err));


// Configuración del servidor 
app.set('puerto', process.env.PORT || 3000);      // Se escogerá un puerto definido o por defecto el puerto 3000

// Middleware use
app.use(morgan('dev'));          // Permite ver por consola las peticiones HTTP que llegan al servidor
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));  // Convierte las peticiones del cliente ...
app.use(bodyParser.json());  // ... y las pasa a formato JSON
app.use(cors());  //Deshabilitar los cors  

// Arranque del servidor
app.listen(app.set('puerto'), () => {
 console.log(`API Rest corriendo en el puerto ${app.get('puerto')}`);
});

// Rutas    
app.use('/api/', routes);
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenido a la comunidad. Te invito a hacer el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y leer [¿cómo preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea bien recibida por parte de la comunidad. Además, para poder reproducir tu problema y encontrar una solución fácilmente nos sería de gran ayuda un [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Como mínimo comparte el código del `fetch` y el mensaje de error que te lanza la consola de depuración de javascript.

Comment: puedes poner el código donde inicializas el server? Estas usando express y que versión? Si es así tienes el middleware para parsear el body de la request a json?

Comment: Sí mira, te pongo el index.js que es donde se inicializa el server. Gracias por la atención!

Comment: creo que las rutas deben ir antes de `app.listen` `app.use('/api/', routes);`

Comment: nada, sigue igual. El cuerpo de la Request está vacío... no sé. He probado miles de cosas y nada. Lo raro es que con Postman me lo hace todo bien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

comprueba primero que tu backend funcione con Postman.

luego una opción para conectarte puede ser la siguiente:

```
async function userExists(rut) {
    var url = 'TUAPI',
      params = {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        body: JSON.stringify({ 'parametro': valorDelParametro }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      };

    var request = new Request(url, params);
    var resp_aux

    fetch(request)
      .then(res => resp_aux = res.clone())
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {

        console.log(resp_aux.status)
        //si el usuario existe.
        if (resp_aux.status === 200) {
          console.log('estado(200) --> el usuario existe') 
          console.log(res['user']._id)
          console.log('el usuario existe ,solo se debe registrar la iniciativa')

        }
        else {

        }

      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
        return "error";
      })
```

porque uso auxiliares:
1.- porque primero necesito la respuesta del servicio (200,400,500) y luego necesito un _ID que me responde la base.

tienes que tener ojo con Fetch que responde una promesa  que solo vive dentro de sus parámetros

en esta parte tienes que fijarte bien que responde tu API , en mi caso me envía el JSON con la glosa usuario

```
console.log(res['user']._id)
```

JSON:

```
{
    "user": {
        "_id": "111111"
        "status": "xxxxx",
        "password": "xxxxx",
        "__v": 0
    }
}
```

espero te sirva.

Comment: Muchas gracias! Al final encontré otra alternativa pero así también me funcionó.